# What to consider when putting a router inside of another network, not controlled by me?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

this question is a question from an users point of view, and a noob regarding network technology.
I am living in an appartement block, where the internet is routed central (lets call it that way). Meaning, I do not have to care about the network, I can just put in a LAN-cable in the box in the wall, connect it to my computer and I get internet. My IP-adress then goes like 10.xx.xx.xx, which shows me that I am in a "bigger network". For my part, I do not need any connection to other devices in the network, but the internet connection.
For wireless LAN I since had bought an access point, leading to WiFi, the IP adresses of all devices still being in the same subspace 10.xx.xx.xx.

Because I now need a second LAN-Port and faster WiFi, I looked around for Access Points with better specifications, but could find none in my price class, but many routers.

Would it be any problem if I used a router instead of an access point or would the router interfere with the upper network in any way?

Thanks in advance

*Addendum: No connection to devices in the bigger network because of an own subnet would be no problem, but a benefit regarding security, as long as I keep the internet connection.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a router!  Use a router!  Use a router!  Did I make myself clear?

The way you described the network configuration you should be able to see everyone and everyone should be able to see you.  That is a big security risk.  Period

A router will provide network address translation (NAT) as well as a firewall so you can see them (if they don't have a router and you know their IP address) but they cannot see you.  You are much better protected with a router and a firewall.

Comment: Without a router, they can see every packet he sends to the Internet, and with a router they can see every packet he sends to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Most AP's are routers as well.  I don't think you can buy a pure AP bridge anymore.  It'll probvably work just fine.  Although sometimes some protocols/services will not work correctly.  There isn't anything you can do about that.  I've seen this happen before and it was to do with a double NAT.  NAT by your router and NAT by the building router.

There are many AP/Routers to choose from.  It sounds like you're on a tight budget.  Have a look a Mikrotik.  They are inexpensive but provide lots of features.  Other brands like DLINK or Linksys are also fine.  Mikrotik can be a bit techy to set up, but the newer firmwares have a quick setup page.

Admittedly, if I were you I'd probably do the same thing.  Not trust that there is isolation on your segment of the network and not put up with shared building Wifi.

However, a well managed and set up building wouldn't need users to do this.  The ports in each apartment would be on their own vlan along with wifi.  In practice it's probably a naive assumption and wifi provided in appartment buildings are often terrible.  Partly because everyone does what you're doing and there is so much interferance that all suffer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using a router is that by default it will probably have DHCP enabled, and thus it will assign IP addresses. While this is useful to you, it could also wreak havoc on your building management's network setup. I've had this experience while managing network access in a college dormitory. I strongly suggest that instead of investing in anything, FIRST speak to whomever manages the network for your building and make sure that whatever you install grooves with their setup.

Comment: Great advice, in general, Kate.  The local network administrator is the source of authority to answer questions of equipment suitability. 

For your benefit, while consumer routers do indeed have DHCP servers, and a rogue DHCP server can wreak havoc upon a network's normal functioning, these routers do not issue DHCP leases over their WAN ports, just their LAN and WLAN interfaces.

So, as long as only the WAN port is used to connect to other networks, its DHCP server will not have an adverse effect.  

And, if the WAN port is not used, the router will usually not have an Internet connection.